# (LibGX+RoboVM) some particular .caf audio files are not played back

Tags: libgdx, robovm

I am trying to port libGDX game to iOS with RoboVM.
I have converted .ogg files to .caf files. All converted .caf files work on Mac. 
The problem is that some of .caf files are not played back on my iPad (still work on the iPhone). Android and Desktop versions of this game have no issues with audio.

Comment: Not exactly the answer you are looking for but mp3 files works fine in my case.

Comment: .mp3 instead of .caf works for me. The reason is bad ogg-caf convertor. thanks!